# get last inserted/added item from QMap

Tags: c++, qt

I have following data structure:

```
typedef QMap<QPair<QString, QString>, QString> UeTypeLoggedUsersData;
```

The purpose of this data structure is to store logged users information.
Now, I can insert data with `insert()`, remove data with `remove()`, iterate over it with `iterator` and it works perfectly. But, how do I **get last added record from `QMap`**? I've been reading [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#details) but I simply cannot find wanted information. The data is orders by the key, here is sample debug output:

```
"c85bc9f7-704f-418e-98af-a1528622dd42" "1" ""
"c85bc9f7-704f-418e-98af-a1528622dd42" "10" ""
"c85bc9f7-704f-418e-98af-a1528622dd42" "12" ""
"c85bc9f7-704f-418e-98af-a1528622dd42" "4" ""
"c85bc9f7-704f-418e-98af-a1528622dd42" "7" ""
"c85bc9f7-704f-418e-98af-a1528622dd42" "9" ""
```

However, from debug process I know (in this situation), the record
**"c85bc9f7-704f-418e-98af-a1528622dd42" "4" ""**
was last added to data structure. How do I, as I asked before, get last added record in this data structure?

Comment: `QMap` does not store its items chronologically. If you need such behavior use `QVector` or `QList` instead. Another option is using an integer as key  type of the map. In that case the higher key value correspond to the last position in the map.

Comment: maybe all you need is a vector? How often do you uses `Qmap::find\lowerBound\UpperBound`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, you wouldn't need such complex and potentially hard to manage data structure. You could define your own class called `UserData` and then in order to store them you can define a `QList<UserData>`.

I think you would need a *bag* of user data, not an ordered list. If so, `QList` exactly fits your requirement.

- `QList::first()` returns first item.
- `QList::last()` returns last item.

---

### Avoiding duplicates

To avoid duplicate entries, I suggest that in your `UserData` class, overload the `==` operator so that semantically defines which two instances of this class are equal. Afterward, you can use `contains` method of `QList` to check whether an item already exists in the list or not.

```
class UserData {
    public:
        bool operator == (const UserData &another){
            return this.key == another.key;
        }

    private:
        QString key;
}
```

Now, you can check for duplicates like this:

```
if(!mList.constains(userData)){
    mList.append(userData);
}
```

Comment: I am working on this option, but the fact that I must NOT have duplicate entries in data structure is why I've choosen `QMap` at first.

Comment: @KernelPanic To avoid duplicate entries, you can check it before you're going to add a new entry.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can't.

`QMap` in Qt implementation of red-black-tree-based dictionary. Such as hash-table where key, value pairs stores arbitrarily sorted by keys. So it provides fast lookup of the value associated with a key. It doesn't store/contains any internal information about values inserted by key in time manner.

If you need such information you should use more complex structure for this. For example:

```
typedef QHash<QString, QStringList> UeTypeLoggedUsersData;
```

So you can use "c85bc9f7-704f-418e-98af-a1528622dd42" as key. As i see you have regular data structure, so you can store value as key subpart and data as values of QStringList:

```
QString key = "c85bc9f7-704f-418e-98af-a1528622dd42";
if (myHash.contains(key)) {
    myHash[key] << "10";
    myHash[key] << "some data";
} else {
    QStringList usersData;
    usersData << "10"
    usersData << "some data"
    myHash[key] = usersData;
}
```

So it more complex but you always can get the latest added value.

Comment: Note: in Qt 4.x `"The QMap class is a template class that provides a skip-list-based dictionary."`

Answer (score 2):

`QMap` is a sorted container - new entries are not inserted chronologically but based on the key. So, `last()` would not refer to the last inserted but to the element with the "largest" key.

The simplest way would be to keep track of the last inserted element manually, `insert()` returns an iterator, so you can make a wrapper around `QMap` that stores that iterator after each insert.